# Should I remove extra corn plants?

Tags: corn

When I bought a sixpack of corn seedlings from the nursery, one of containers had three seedlings. I planted them anyway without thinning them down to just one. They have now grown to over a foot high. Will it hurt them to leave them as is? Or should I thin them now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you should separate them now.  The corn plants that I have seen, grow 1-2 feet in diameter.  And you need that spread for the leaves to expand and make enough food.

If you leave the plants close together, they will bend away from each other, and probably grow up long spindly and weak.